# can we get log time complexity using a single array for graph lookup and connect operation?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

can we perform graph lookup( A and B is connected or not?) and connect( connect A and B) in log time using a single array?

I learned some algo like:

**quick find** (linear time in connect and constant time in lookup) - single array

**quick union**(constant time connect and average n/2 in lookup) - single array

**weighted union**(log time in lookup and constant connect time) but this algorithm requires 2 array, one for nodes and another for number of nodes connected for each node.

I am asking just for curiosity. Is it possible to get weighted union sort of complexity using a single array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Disjoint-Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). It works as a forest, but you can always use an array to implement this forest, with an array of `roots`, instead of the `root` field per node.

The armotized complexity of this implementation is **sub-logarithmic**, and is often labled as `O(log*(n))`

Comment: It's even better than O(log* n); it's O(alpha(n)), where alpha is the Ackermann inverse function, which grows so slowly that it's effectively five for any input that could be feasibly entered.

Comment: @templatetypedef: As I understood it, it acts similar to `log*(n)`, which is `log(log(log(....(n)..))` [which is also practically smaller then 5 for any realistic number], though I might be wrong about it. Care to give a short explanation if I am?

Comment: My understanding is that the Ackermann inverse is asymptotically smaller than log*.  I will have to double-check that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Disjoint-Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). You can find a very simple explanation [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=disjointDataStructure)